# Remove markers that are not in proximity to linestring

Tags: json, leaflet, geojson

I'm building a map with leaflet and I get my lines and markers from .geojson and I'm wondering if its possible to remove markers that are not in proximity to the lines, if so how?

EDIT:

```
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/utsp9zh3/
```

In that example, how do I hide or remove testmarker4 (and others like it if it existed) that are not close or touching the lines.

Comment: Pls share your code what you have tried (or the minimum what you have to do, is to share the data and your code)

Comment: Please see the jsfiddle i added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your code:

```
var loadcount = 0;
Test.on('data:loaded',()=>{
    loadcount++;
  if(loadcount >= 2){
        removeMarkerIfToFar(Test,LineRouteTest)
  
  }
});
LineRouteTest.on('data:loaded',()=>{
    loadcount++;
  if(loadcount >= 2){
        removeMarkerIfToFar(Test,LineRouteTest)  
  }
})

var MINIMUM_DIS = 1000; // 1km


function removeMarkerIfToFar(markerGroup, lineGroup){
    var lineLatLngs = [];
    lineGroup.eachLayer((layer)=>{
    if(layer._latlngs){ // check if no point
        lineLatLngs = lineLatLngs.concat(layer.getLatLngs());
    }
  })
  
  markerGroup.eachLayer((layer)=>{
    if(layer instanceof L.Marker){
        var remove = true;
      lineLatLngs.forEach((latlng)=>{
        if(latlng.distanceTo(layer.getLatLng()) <=  MINIMUM_DIS){
            remove = false;
        }
      })
      
      if(remove){
        layer.remove()
      }      
    }
  })
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/8r1aw7u0/